# Syntax for accessing nested array elements in PHP double quotes string

Tags: php, reference

I'm attempting to access a nested array element within a double quotes string, like this:

```
"$variable[first_index][second_index]";
```

This is throwing an *Array to string conversion* notice and halting my script.

Is there a correct syntax for accessing the data within a string in this manner, or do I need to set a temp variable to reference the required data, and then use THAT in the string?

Comment: don't put it in the double quotes

Comment: hmm. OK, if that's the only workaround, post an answer and I'll except it. I need to also use \r\n, that's the reasoning for using double quotes but I suppose I can always just append that part to the end of the string after the fact - thanks!

Comment: `echo $varable[index]."\n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
$string = "Value is {$variable["first_index"]["second_index"]}";
```

It's called complex extended variable syntax and it's very useful. You can access fields of an object inside string in double quotes, as well as nested array.

Comment: @ineedhelp I always go for this approach and recommend that you do.  This avoids having bounce between literal strings and variables via concatenation.  Your text editor will/should highlight these variables properly which improves readability.  After all, double quotes are specifically designed/used in php to permit variables within the string.